# How to change the title bar icon?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I need to change the title bar icon of the Internet Explorer. Iam using IE v.6.
I tried using Favicon but its changing only the address bar icon and if we add the page to the favorites or bookmark its displaying the icon!!! but its not changing the title bar icon of the IE. 
Note : I want the icon to be changed programatically not manually.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If this question no longer requires additional answers, please mark the appropriate post as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

The title bar icon is built-in to IE. No webpage can change that icon.

Comment: Apart from IE9 where you can change all the icons, and even have overlay icons if your website is pinned :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg131029(VS.85).aspx and scroll down to "Customizing a website launched from a pinned site" - but note that this is Windows 7 Only.

Answer (score 1):

[WM_SETICON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632643%28VS.85%29.aspx).